# How to remove an event handler without a reference to the handler function?

Tags: javascript, events

I have a DOM element with an event handler attached using `addEventListener`. By the time I want to remove it with `removeEventListener`, I no longer have a reference to the function that handles the event.
How can I remove the event listener, other than storing references to all event handlers globally?

I noticed that if I edit the DOM element using the Chrome developer tools, the event is no longer handled. Could a viable solution lie herein?

I'm not using and unable to use a library like jQuery in this particular situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't; you need that reference. Either store it globally like you suggest yourself, or store it in the DOM element like Aaron Digulla said.

Answer (score 0):

Store a reference to the event handler in the DOM element:

```
 e.handlerToRemove = handler;
 e.addEventListener( ..., handler );
```

Later:

```
 e.removeEventListener( e.handlerToRemove );
```